# How to open TFS Workspace in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

Why am I not seeing any TFS icons next to the icons in my project? I have this project in TFS 2012 Express and I used the get command to download it to my Local Path. Then I went to Visual Studio's File > Open Project command and opened the file. Is this not the way you add a Team project to the solution explorer?

Notice in the screenshot below that there are no blue locks or plus signs to indicated the status of the file on the server.

[image]

Comment: No. Use Team->Connect to Team Foundation Server.

Comment: I've done that but now I need to edit some files and then recheck them back in. How do I do that?

Comment: Personally, I double-click on the "Source Control" node in Team Explorer to bring up the "Source Control Explorer", I then navigate to the solution or project I want, and double-click. If you're still getting no icons after that, then perhaps the files haven't actually been added to source control. What happens when you right-click one of those files and choose "View History"?

Comment: I do all of that and when I click "View History" I see the history. The problem is that when I double-click on the .sln file, the solution opens into the Solution Explorer but it's not version controlled.

Comment: And what do you see when you click "View History" after right-clicking a file in **Solution** Explorer?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to click the Bind button and bind the TFS server to the project

Comment: You should create an answer to this question giving the details of how you did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I double-clicked on the solution file, the solution was not bound to the TFS. I got a dialog box that had a bind button and it bound the solution to the TFS and everything is now version controlled.

Comment: If you have a similar problem in future, you can manually handle the bindings (if the project is already in source control) by going to `File` > `Source Control` > `Change Source Control...`